# Accessing the controller associated with a directive instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have associated a controller with a directive like so:

```
return function MyDirective() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        restrict: 'E',
        template: template,
        controller: 'myController',
        replace: true,
    };
};
```

If I want to access a method on the controller from the template, do I need to add the controller to a property on the scope?

Template:

```
<div> 
  <div> 
    <button ng-click="doSomething()">Do something.</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function MyController() {}

MyController.prototype.doSomething() {
  window.alert('foo');
}
```

Comment: Nope, just call the method.

Comment: Like `<button ng-click="myControllerMethod"></button>`?

Comment: Declare it just a normal method. E.g. `ng-click="myControllerMethod()"`. Remove the curly braces.

Comment: Either use `controllerAs: "vm"` and access with `ng-click="vm.someFunction()"` where you have `this.someFunction = function(){}` in the controller, or expose `someFunction` on the scope and access it like you would any other scope variable: `$scope.someFunction = function(){}`

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. `<button ng-click="doSomething()">Do something</button>` does not appear to invoke the controller method. I am investigating the use of `controller as`.

Comment: @BenAston It should work if you properly declared it. Can you provide the code of your template?

Comment: `<div>
 <div>
  <button ng-click="doSomething()">Do something.</button>
 </div>
</div>
` So it should look on the controller methods for `doSomething`?

Comment: you can't associate your controllers functions with the scope and use them in this directive though, since OP created a new scope instance with `scope: {}` I believe.

Comment: @SamHuckaby So by using an isolate scope, controller methods cannot be used directly?

Comment: @BenAston Also, can you provide the code of your controller.

Comment: @SamHuckaby Since the scope that the directive will use are in the controller isolated scope has nothing to do with it. The scope/s are already declared in the controller itself.

Comment: @BenAston, by using an isolated scope, you are creating a new scope for your directive, separate from the scope of your controller. I would recommend using the controllerAs and then referencing functions that are declared on the controller like New Dev suggested.

Comment: @SamHuckaby. OK that works. If someone can make that the ans I will accept.

Comment: @BenAston, my bad, I was mistaken with what I thought was happening. Like Alberto said, the isolated scope shouldn't matter, since they are at the same level. Have you declared your controllers function on the scope inside your controller?

Comment: @BenAston would you mind editing your question to include your template and your controller's code?

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid `scope: {}` from your directive to access controller functions because of `scope: {}` in your directive create isolate scope from your controller.

That's why you may can not access controller functions from your directive template.

after avoid `scope: {}` use functions like normal controller functions.

Like:

```
<button data-ng-click="myFunction()">call my function</button>
```

you can use *scope* in link function in your directive.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs)
```